# The discord.js code is not working correct

Tags: discord.js

I made the code so that I could write on behalf of a bot in discord. But when I write in the main channel in order for the bot to send my message to another channel, my bot writes where I wrote it, and starts spamming adding its own mention, although in the code I indicated not him but the person who wrote this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqgja.jpg)

This is what the code looks like.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.channel.id === "735573900251103244") {
      let csl1 = message.channel.name.split("-")[0];
      let csl2 = message.channel.name.split("-")[1];
      let logs = bot.guilds.cache.get("611212397226491904").channels.cache.get("611215326566416416");
      if (message.author.id === "546359252575322122") {
        message.channel.send(message.content);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}>` + `${message.content}`);
      }
      return;
    }
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    let help = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let cmd;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if(bot.commands.has(help)) {
      cmd = bot.commands.get(help);
    } else {
      cmd = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(help));
    }
    if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args);
});
```

Comment: You need to reorder your conditions, check for the author and channel type before the ID

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to reorder your checking of message.author.bot to the beginning of the function as seblor mentioned.

Furthermore, `message.channel` refers to the channel that the bot received the message in. In order to send a message to a *different* channel, you'll have to do the following:

```
// https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch
bot.channels.fetch(targetchannelid).then((chan) => {
    chan.send("blah blah blah");
});
```

Comment: The problem is that when the order of conditions is changed, the bot stops reactivating everything in bot.on('message', async message

Comment: if you move `if (message.author.bot) return` to the beginning of the callback for bot.on, it'll prevent your bot from triggering on itself or other bots.